# Does benchmark in java good for compared modular arithmatic operations?

Tags: java, performance, math, benchmarking

Can I rely on the results of the benchmark in java to compare the calculations such as modular arithmetic to compare between two operation for example

A = B x C MOD N

D = E^-1 MOD N

Q1)
I want to know.
Multiplication equivalent amount of time to find the inverted
If answer yes. Please suggest how that works.

Q2)
I've got a question about benchmarks in Java, in particular.
Does UNIX OS better than WXP OS when use Java benchmar Rather UNIX OS give us best results or no?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?  What could you possibly mean by "better"?  More accurate?  As compared to what?

Comment: I mean  More accurate, for example compare between runtime Is this operand (A = B x C MOD N) faster than this operand D = E^-1 MOD N or vice versa . also which more accurate with jave. Is  UNIX OS more accurate WXP OS or vise versa

Comment: Can you rely on the result of *what* benchmark? What's the question here?

Comment: "More accurate" compared to what?  If you benchmark on Unix, you'll get results that are more representative of performance on Unix.  If you benchmark on Windows, you'll get results that are more representative of performance on Windows.  If you benchmark on Tuesdays, you'll get results that are more representative of performance on Tuesdays.

Answer (score 0):

1. Multiplication is typically faster than modular inversion since modular inversion tends to require many multiplications. (Depends on the algorithm you are using, though.)
2. Integer arithmetic is accurate everywhere, Unix and Windows are the same.

Comment: thank YOU FOR ALL.I still have something I did not understand here you say modular inversion tends to require many multiplications. (Depends on the algorithm you are using) in java when we write this line  K =(K1.modInverse(P)) compiler's java compute k1 inverse depends on any algorithm here. Can you give me any link about this Wondered.

Comment: You can find the source code at docjar.com. Search for BigInteger.